# Using tikzpicture to customize labels in enumerate shifts item text below label level

Tags: tikz-pgf, itemize, labels, enumitem, alignment

[image: What I Get with the code.]Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tcbuselibrary{vignette}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label={\begin{tikzpicture}\node[draw,fill=blue!15!white] (A) {FACT};\tcbvignette{outside node=A,raised color=blue}
    \end{tikzpicture}}]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[1]
        \end{itemize}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I don't think it's that easy since here the TikZ picture is the label and the linespacing will be inconsistent even if `[baseline=(A.base)]` is used.

Comment: Use `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.base), overlay] \node[draw,fill=blue!15!white] (A) {FACT}; \tcbvignette{outside node=A, raised color=blue} \path[overlay=false] ([xshift=-2mm]A.west) ([xshift=2mm]A.east); \end{tikzpicture}` where `2mm` is the default `size` for the vignette. This makes the picture have a width for the proper positioning but no height so that it doesn't interfere with the linespacing of the paragraphs.

Comment: Good point @Qrrbrbirlbel. The proposed solution deserves an answer rather than a comment :)